# Using the new operator in Struts v1 Action classes

Tags: thread-safety, struts-1

I know that instances variables in a Struts 1 Action class are ill-advised because of the thread safety issue. However, within an Action class can I instantiate an object of some other class using the new operator and expect each thread to then retain its own instance of that object, or is the new object multi-threaded also?

Comment: Show us what you intend to do. If you're only using local variables, you're safe. If you're using fields, you're not.

Comment: Within the body of the Action class I say: Foobar foobar = new Foobar(). Foobar is a public class in the same package as the Action class. Now, is the foobar object thread-safe by virtue of the fact that the new operator allocates exactly one Foobar object for each thread, or is the Foobar object multi-theaded like the Action class itself?

Comment: Show us some code. I still don't know if you're doing it in a method of the action class, or in the action class itself. It's completely different. What's sure is that the new operatior doesn't allocate exactly one Foobar object for each thread. It allocates one each time it's invoked.

Comment: public class MyAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
                                 ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

     Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
     Object returnValue = foobar.getReturnValue();
     return mapping.findForward("EXIT");

    }
 
}

Is foobar thread-safe? Is returnValue thread-safe?